# Understanding OCP(place) and CodaCond constraints in Optimality Theory

Tags: optimality-theory

I'm having trouble finding examples or definitions for these two constraints and can't fully grasp it. If anyone could direct me to a resource or maybe explain it, I would be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

CodaCond is short for "Coda Condition", and, according to [McCarthy (2008: 225)](https://books.google.com/books?id=XnW73qKdwB8C&pg=RA7-PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false), is violated once per "consonant place specification that is not linked with an onset consonant (Ito 1989). Sometimes used as a cover constraint for a collection of restrictions on consonant clusters that includes the Coda-Condition proper."

OCP is presumably short for "[Obligatory Contour Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obligatory_Contour_Principle)", which stated "adjacent identical tones are prohibited" but has been extended to segments and features, so, if I understand correctly, OCP(place) prohibits a succession of segments with the same place features.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ocp%28place%29) are some examples of OCP-place (not all, but most of them), and here are examples of [CodaCond](https://www.google.com/search?q=codacond).

Comment: Did you mean to use a different link?